# How to merge div with clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">Content1...</div>
    <div class="child">Content2...</div>
    <div class="child">Content3...</div>
    <div class="child">Content4...</div>
    <div class="child">Content5...</div>
    <div class="child">Content6...</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery code**

```
clone_object = $("#parent>div:lt(2)").clone();
```

I tried following code but it do not give any result.

```
clone_object.add($("<div class='clear'></div>"));
```

**Expected output**

```
<div class="child">Content1...</div>
<div class="child">Content2...</div>
<div class='clear'></div>
```

My Question is how to merge `div` with created clone?

Comment: try `append` instead of `add`.

Comment: @Mr_Green I tried it do not work

Comment: btw, why do you want to add a extra div? it seems you are adding it to clear the float.. is it so?

Comment: Yes, I required to clear float after created clone.

Comment: Don't do that. use `:after` pseudo class to clear the float.

Comment: @Mr_Green Can you write code how to write?

Comment: Check the below solution.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use jquery to clear the float. Use css as shown below:

```
#parent:after{
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8aL2Lkk/)**

Comment: @Sadikhasan you said you are trying to add that div with class to **clear the float** right?

Comment: Yes, But there is many situation where I want to add clear div dynamically. That's why I needed

Comment: @Sadikhasan I still think this should work because it will not harm the layout unless you are using pseudo classes already to the parent element.

Comment: Understand my situation I need add div dynamically to clear float.

Answer (score 0):

```js
clone_object = $("#parent>div:lt(2)").clone();
newObj = $('<div class="clear"></div>');
var obj = $.extend({}, clone_object, newObj);

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">Content1...</div>
    <div class="child">Content2...</div>
    <div class="child">Content3...</div>
    <div class="child">Content4...</div>
    <div class="child">Content5...</div>
    <div class="child">Content6...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you check my expected output?